# What are required and how to connect TTL finger print module to Raspberry pi 3

Tags: php, android, mysql, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

I would like to take a finger print from the user and store it in database using raspberry pi and it should send a notification to my app. I have done with app but i am unable to move forward in connecting a TTL finger print module to raspberry pi.

I am new to this, I don't know what to be used, how to code etc.

Can someone please help me

I want answer for the following questions

1) How to connect TTL finger print scanner to raspberry pi
2) What are the libraries required in python for finger print scanner
3) How to retrieve and store the finger print in my sql database.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather large answer that isn't appropriate for this forum. What have you tried? What don't you understand? Beyond that I can guess at what you need, there is some pretty decent hardware,  libraries that you will have to tinker with out there.

Hardware:

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11792

I recommend this because I bought it. It seems pretty easy to set up. It is very tricky to get to work on the pi. I have not figured that part out yet. It is very touchy on the UART stuff.

As far as already written libraries:

https://github.com/QuickGroup/pyGT511C3

This one you will need to put in quite a bit of time to get the fingerprint scanner to work properly. I have not been very successful with it yet.

https://github.com/the-AjK/GT-511C3

This one uses Node.js and is supposed to be better on working, but has some compatibility issues with the raspberry pi between versions.

As to how to retrieve and store:

I wouldn't recommend storing them in your own personal anything. I would recommend having a key/id of some sort be associated with a registered fingerprint from the scanner.